# How to access an object's declarations with actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I would like to iterate through an object's validators. Validators must be declared in a declarations tag. How does one scroll through declarations? If one cannot, is there a better of locating all validators other than scrolling through all properties of an object?

Comment: I don't understand the question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the Validators in a collection (an Array for instance). After that you can simply loop over the collection's items.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Array id="validators">
        <mx:StringValidator source="{firstnameInput}" property="text" required="true" />
        <mx:StringValidator source="{lastnameInput}" property="text" required="true" />
        <mx:EmailValidator source="{emailInput}" property="text" required="true" />
        <mx:DateValidator source="{dateInput}" property="text" required="false" />
    </fx:Array>
</fx:Declarations>
```

You can then simply use 'validateAll()':

```
Validator.validateAll(validators);
```

or loop over the Validators:

```
for each (var validator:Validator in validators) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you want to iterate over all properties of a class (including meta tags), you can use [describeType](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29).

To include meta tags, make sure you've set the appropriate compiler option `keep-as3-metadata` correctly.